# How to change participant number to a specific value?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I recently started using R, while having never coded before, so I find myself a bit stuck on the following problem:

I have two dataframes (with different row and column lengths) that I need to merge. The merging itself isn't the problem, but I have a problem with the difference in variables in my two dataframes. The first dataframe depicts the participants as -1, -2, -3, etc. My second dataframe depicts participants as STR_PP001, STR_PP002, STR_PP003, etc.

The goal is to have all data combined in one dataframe that depicts the participants as STR_PP001 (or whatever number that specific participant is). Is there a way I can transform the column in my first dataframe so it displays the participant codes as STR_PP instead of -1?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many participants do you have?

Comment: Are -1, -2, -3 etc. equivalent to  STR_PP001, STR_PP002, STR_PP003 ie are these three (-1,-2,-3) depicting the other three? And what happens after -999?

Comment: My data goes up to -128, but I have a total of 116 participants, due to some participants being excluded completely and thus having no data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This nested `ifelse` statement using `gsub`and backreference works:

```
a <- c("-1", "-3", "-10", "-55", "-100", "-112")

ifelse(grepl("-\\d$", a),  paste0("STR_PP00", gsub("-(\\d)", "\\1", a)),
       ifelse(grepl("-\\d{2}$", a),  paste0("STR_PP0", gsub("-(\\d+)", "\\1", a)), 
              paste0("STR_PP", gsub("-(\\d+)", "\\1", a))))

[1] "STR_PP001" "STR_PP003" "STR_PP010" "STR_PP055" "STR_PP100" "STR_PP112"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example Data:**

```
a <- paste0("-", 1:4)
a
#[1] "-1" "-2" "-3" "-4"
```

**Name Transformation**

```
b <- paste0("STR_PP00", sapply(strsplit(a, "-"),"[[", 2))
b
#[1] "STR_PP001" "STR_PP002" "STR_PP003" "STR_PP004"
```

Essentially what this code snippet does is split by "-", where the output of `strsplit()` is a list. We then utilize `sapply()` to chose the second element of every vector within our list. After that one can utilize `paste0()` to stick together the extracted number and the prefix you desire.

---

**Update to also accomodate for higher ID's**

```
a <- paste0("-", 1:128)
b <- "STR_PP"
# Amount of zeros required, -1 because of the "-" that is counted in nchar() 
# -3 becasue the maximum length is 3 for id > 99 and times -1 because we 
# want positive numbers

zerolen <- ((nchar(a) - 1) - 3) * (-1)

# Now one can add the amount of required 0 based on the length of ID number

c <- sapply(zerolen, function(x){
paste(as.character((rep(0, x))), collapse = "")
})

# Again combine with paste()

paste0(b, c, sapply(strsplit(a, "-"),"[[", 2))

# Which results in:

head(paste0(b, c, sapply(strsplit(a, "-"),"[[", 2)), 20)

#  [1] "STR_PP001" "STR_PP002" "STR_PP003" "STR_PP004" "STR_PP005" 
#      "STR_PP006" "STR_PP007" "STR_PP008" "STR_PP009" "STR_PP010"
# [11] "STR_PP011" "STR_PP012" "STR_PP013" "STR_PP014" "STR_PP015" 
#      "STR_PP016" "STR_PP017" "STR_PP018" "STR_PP019" "STR_PP020"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I tried it out and it works great! My only issue now is that I have a total of 128 participants. The idea is that participant number 10, for example, should be depicted as STR_PP010 and participant 101, for example, should be depicted as STR_PP101. When I would use the code you opted, it would give me STR_PP0010 and STR_PP00101.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: This would work: `ifelse(grepl("-\\d{1}$", a),  paste0("STR_PP00", sapply(strsplit(a, "-"),"[[", 2)),
       ifelse(grepl("-\\d{2}$", a),  paste0("STR_PP0", sapply(strsplit(a, "-"),"[[", 2)), 
              paste0("STR_PP", sapply(strsplit(a, "-"),"[[", 2))))`

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works beautiful and I'm getting closer now! However, I have one last issue (I should have mentioned this in my original question, I realise now): My participants go up to -128 (I'll have more in the future), however, there are only 116 participants included (some participants have been completely excluded, so it might go from -3 to -5, skipping -4 completely). If I run the code you proposed now, it just nicely goes from STR_PP001 to STR_PP116, but this will end up giving participants the wrong participant code and thus the wrong data. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could fill the missing values in your  `data.frame()` with NA's. That way you would also gain information on which ID did not respond or lacks important information. However, this is quite a different question than the one u asked in the first place. In order for other people to effectively navigate on this site, the answers should be to the original question. Please write another question regarding the issues you discovered now.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry! I'll make a new post about it. Thank you so much though, to the both of you for helping my out with this bit! This already helped tons and fixed my initial issue!

Answer (score 0):

But one way that will  work for sure:
If you call your variable in the second data frame as VAR you can do this:

```
VAR[which(VAR == -1)] <- "STR_PP001"
```

and so on for the other numbers. If -1 is a character probably you will have to set `VAR[which(VAR == "-1")] <- "STR_PP001"`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! However, right now I have over 100 participants already, with the great possibility of more participants being added in the future. Therefore, I am looking for something I can implement easily and that will also work if I add participants later on. I don't know if there is a way I can do this using your suggestion?